# Simple HTTP Framework and time issue

Tags: java, http, date, http-headers

I'm using [Simple Framework](http://www.simpleframework.org/) for my recent project, and there is a problem with the date headers generated by the system. I can get my local time from Date class correctly, but setDate method of Simple's Response class sets date in milliseconds and when i do that by calling System.currentTimeInMillis, dates in response headers are incorrect. is there any way to solve this problem with Simple Framework? If not, what can i do except calling set method with a date string? Thanks in advance...

**EDIT:** Date in the headers are in wrong timezone. And i also tried Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMilis() method.

Comment: what is incorrect about the date in the headers - is it correct time but in a wrong timezone? Or completely incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your dates in GMT? If not then what are they in. Don't forget the HTTP/1.1 spec says the following.

> RFC 2616                        HTTP/1.1                       June 1999
>
> All HTTP date/time stamps MUST be represented in Greenwich Mean Time
>      (GMT), without exception. For the purposes of HTTP, GMT is exactly
>      equal to UTC (Coordinated Universal Time). This is indicated in the
>      first two formats by the inclusion of "GMT" as the three-letter
>      abbreviation for time zone, and MUST be assumed when reading the
>      asctime format. HTTP-date is case sensitive and MUST NOT include
>      additional LWS beyond that specifically included as SP in the
>      grammar.

Comment: They are in UTC i think, i live in GMT+3 time zone, and last modified header of response is 3 hours earlier, which may cause a cache problem with browsers

Comment: That sounds correct the Date: and Last-Modified: in the HTTP/1.1 response should be three hours out if you live in GMT + 3. Your cache will know because all HTTP/1.1 headers must be in RFC 1123 format which contains the time zone. For example from RFC 2616, "Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT".

Comment: Oh, i see, so i don't have to worry about timezone when it comes to browser caching because it's standard in HTTP implementations, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `Calendar` object? It can easily be converted to milliseconds by calling its `getTimeInMillis()` method:

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
```